# find() in node app mongodb query very confusing

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to get the value of a field located in a document stored in a mongodb collection. My code is not working and I'm not sure why. I know find() returns a cursor object, which I want to traverse using cursor.next(). It seems that point in the code is where it's failing based on my debugging. I'm using the mongodb module for node.js to perform these operations. Here is the code:

Setting up the DB/collection info:

```
exports.login = function(request, response){
    var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
        Server = require('mongodb').Server,
        assert = require('assert'),
        server_config = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true}),
        udb = new Db('users', server_config, {
            w: -1
        }),
        uname = request.body.uName,
        pw =  request.body.uPass;
```

The opening the db and querying:

```
 udb.open(function(err, udb) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        var collection = udb.collection('profiles');
        collection.find({username: uname, password: pw}, function(err, collection){
            if( err || !collection){
                console.log("login fail");
                response.redirect('/');
            }
            else {
                collection.each(function(err, result){
                    assert.equal(null, err);
                    console.log("login success");
                    request.session.loggedIn = true;
                    request.session.user = uname;
                    response.redirect('/userDashboard');
                });
            }
        });
        udb.close();
    });
}
```

I don't seem to be getting any errors, the page just 'hangs' indefinitely.

Comment: Console log things? Make sure you get to certain parts of your code?

Comment: I get inside the else clause and then it hangs. `collection.each(function(err, result){` is where the issue seems to be.

Comment: What about looping through the collection? Does it run one for each?

Comment: It might be not finding anything that matches the query. console log the collection?

Comment: [ 12:00:14 PM ]
db.profiles.find().limit(100)

Comment: If it didn't find anything wouldn't it return a null value instead of a cursor object?

Comment: `var collection = udb.collection('profiles');
        collection.find({username: uname, password: pw}, function(err, collection){` First, I'd change the name so your not calling both collection, but then, I'd make sure that the collection in the callback function isn't `null`

Comment: Just console log it to be sure

Comment: I output the cursor to the console, I saw DB and collection data, including my criteria, but this field might mean nothing found? `'items: [],'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nothing's being found. Test the query in the mongo shell and see if you're getting anything. Also be sure not to store passwords in plain text! Check out the node bcrypt package.

Comment: I don't think I am getting anything, I'm not sure what's wrong with my query. The data is in a record and should match the query.

Comment: Can you get it in the mongo shell?

Comment: The criteria is populated when I do the search in the mongo shell. When I do the query via node it shows the empty find() criteria as noted above.

Comment: Mongo shell: 
db.profiles.find({ "username" : "Jim.James", "password" : "pass" }).limit(50);

Comment: I'd really encourage you to check out mongoose. It makes this stuff far less complex.